# Is a fibre bundle with contractible fibre a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles

As already stated in the title: If $p:E\to X$ is a fibre bundle with a contractible fibre $F$, is $p$ a homotopy equivalence? Or are there stronger conditions we need, e. g. the existence of a section $s:X\to E$?

Comment: Are you requiring connected fibers?

Comment: Since $F$ should be contractible, it is also connected, yes.

Comment: Oh that was a dumb question on my part.  For some reason I was thinking simply connected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the spaces involved are CW-complexes*, then yes.  As $F$ is contractible, the long exact sequence in homotopy groups shows that $p_*: \pi_n(E) \to \pi_n(X)$ is always an isomorphism.  The Whitehead theorem (that a weak h.e. of CW-complexes is an equivalence) now shows that $p$ is a homotopy equivalence.

*or even homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes